# Concatenate strings and expressions in a plot's title

Tags: r, plot, expression, plotmath

How can I combine text and math expressions in a plot's title. If I use paste the expression is converted to character. For example I want something like this as a title

$ARL_1$ curve for $S^2$

Thank you

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You want to read `?plotmath` to see how to do this sort of thing. Here is an example:

```
plot(1:10, main = expression(ARL[1] ~ "curve for" ~ S^2))
```

The `[.]` is subscript, whilst `^` gives superscript. The `~` spaces out the parts of the expression as if there were literal spaces.

**Edit**: normally I would have done:

```
plot(1:10, main = expression(ARL[1] ~ curve ~ for ~ S^2))
```

but that throws an error because `for` is being interpreted as the start of a `for()` loop call.

Comment: Second will work if you use `expression(ARL[1] ~ curve ~ "for" ~ S^2)`.

Comment: @Marek: Oh, yes, agreed. But if you are going to do `"for"` you might as well do `"curve for"`, unless `~` and " " are different amounts of space...?

Comment: Of course. It matters in more complicated cases when one needs to mixed more strings. I add it as completeness ;) On other hand you could also use back-ticks `\``.

Answer (score 33):

You can also use `bquote(paste(...))`,  which is a little more flexible than `expression`: you can include variable values (say, the value of `x`) in the labels with  `.(x)`. For example:

```
x<- 232323
plot(1:10, main = bquote(paste(ARL[1], " curve for ", S^2, "; x=",.(x))))
```

Comment: Yes although I generally find that using the plotmath paste function confuses more than it helps. Try > x<- 232323
> plot(1:10, main = bquote(ARL[1]~"curve for"~S^2~";"~x==.(x)))

Comment: +1 Dwin - introducing `paste` is a pain in the but if you get your `,` or `""` in the wrong places...

Comment: @GavinSimpson Yeah, your answer is nicer. But I thought it would be good to point out a more flexible solution in case somebody comes here looking for a more general solution.

Comment: +1 from me. That comment wasn't a criticism of the substantive point of your answer (`bquote()`), just a point about introducing paste in there if you can avoid it. `bquote()` is underused and very powerful!

Comment: .. another 1+ from me. I thought bquote was an excellent suggestion and only added a very minor demurral to avoid paste when possible, because it often gets confused with that "other paste". People don't realize it's a different function with different sematics and with no sep argument.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `latex2exp::TeX` to convert TeX to expressions on the fly:

```
plot(cars, main = TeX("$ARL_1$ curve for $S^2$"))
```