# Using subscript and variable values at the same time in Axis titles in R

Tags: r, plot

I want to use the title "CO2 emissions in wetlands" in a plot in R, whereas the 2 in CO2 is in subscript, and the value for the region (here: "wetlands") is contained in a variable named "region".

```
region = "wetlands"
plot (1, 1, main=expression(CO[2]~paste(" emissions in ", region)))
```

The problem is, that not the value of the variable is pasted, but the name of the variable. This gives "CO2 emissions in region" instead of "CO2 emissions in wetlands". I also tried:

```
region="wetlands"
plot (1,1,main=paste(expression(CO[2]), "emissions in", region))
```

But the subscript is not done here, and the title is: "CO[2] emissions in wetlands".

Is it somehow possible to get values of variables into expression?

Thanks for your help,

Sven

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302367/concatenate-strings-and-expressions-in-a-plots-title

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no need to use `paste()` in producing an expression for plothmath-style annotation. This works just fine:

```
region <- "foo"
plot (1, 1, main = bquote(CO[2] ~ "emissions in" ~ .(region)))
```

giving:

[image]

Using `paste()` just gets in the way.

Nb: You have to quote `"in"` because the parser grabs it as a key part of R syntax otherwise.

Answer (score 7):

You can use substitute:

```
mn <- substitute(CO[2]~ "emissions in" ~ region, list(region="wetlands") )
plot(1, 1, main=mn )
```

[image: substitute plot]

From the `?substitute` help file:

> The typical use of substitute is to create informative labels for
>   data sets and plots. The myplot example below shows a simple use of
>   this facility. It uses the functions deparse and substitute to create
>   labels for a plot which are character string versions of the actual
>   arguments to the function myplot.

Comment: Just an addition: If you need to cancatenate variables in expression without adding spaces, you can use x*y instead of x~y according to `?plotmath`

Answer (score 2):

For your case, stolen from one of the answers at the duplicated link:

```
x <- "OberKrain"
plot(1:10, 1:10, main = bquote(paste(CO[2], " in ", .(x))))
```

[image]

Comment: Roman, your code doesn't work.  It returns "OberKrein" instead of "wetlands." :-D

Comment: it does not work for me either: > substitute("T[a]max")
[1] "T[a]max"; bquote("T[a]max")
[1] "T[a]max". According to your example, the "a" between brackets should appear in subscript. isnt it?

Comment: @Aguscamacho check your syntax. You should not be using `;` in this context.