# How to include subscript in text for plot point labels

Tags: r, text, plot, subscript

Hi I'm new to R so I apologise if this is a very basic question.
I'm trying to add text to a plot at point 11 on the x axis and point 900 on the y axis that will read `t0= -4.0280` with the 0 as subscript. Where `t0 <- -4.0280`
 To do this I've tried:

```
text(11,900,paste("t[0]=",t0),cex=0.8) 
# which gives 
't[0]= -4.0280'

text(11,900,expression(paste("t[0]=",t0)),cex=0.8) 
# which gives 
't[0]=t0'

# the closest I've gotten is:    
text(11,900,expression(paste(t[0]==t0)),cex=0.8)
```

which will use subscript but return `t0` instead of my value of -4.0280.

Could anyone show me where Ive gone wrong?

Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can replace `expression` with `substitute`. There's no need for the `paste`. The argument `list(t0 = t0)` tells `substitute` to replace the string `t0` with the value of the object `t0`:

```
plot(1,1)

t0 <- 1.3

text(1, 0.8, substitute(t[0]==t0, list(t0 = t0)), cex = 0.8)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Slightly shorter than `substitute` is with `bquote`:

```
plot(1,1)
t0 <- -4.0280
text(1, 0.8, bquote("t"[0] ~ "=" ~ .(t0)))
```

of if you'd like to use `paste` in there:

```
text(1, 0.8, (bquote("t"[0]~.(paste0('=',t0)))))
```

[image]

This kind of Q has popped up previously:

[Using subscript and variable values at the same time in Axis titles in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024849/using-subscript-and-variable-values-at-the-same-time-in-axis-titles-in-r)

[Concatenate strings and expressions in a plot's title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302367/concatenate-strings-and-expressions-in-a-plots-title)

Comment: Thanks guys, both of those answers worked great. Just to be clear, when should I use 'paste' if this wasn't the correct use?

Comment: Here is an example of a few uses of `paste `  http://stackoverflow.com/a/15506875/1036500

Comment: I've edited my answer to show how you might use `paste` here, but it's not the most efficient way. I generally use `paste` to create character vectors rather than objects that include variables like your example. That said, I sometimes do something like `eval(parse(text=paste0("examp",i))` where the paste result is evaluated, but this is considered bad practice - `library(fortunes);fortune(106)`