# R scientific notation in plots

Tags: r, plot, scientific-notation

I have a simple plot:

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript                                                                                    

png('plot.png')

y <- c(102, 258, 2314)                                                                         
x <- c(482563, 922167, 4462665)

plot(x,y)
dev.off()
```

R uses 500, 1000, 1500, etc for the y axis. Is there a way I can use scientific notation for the `y` axis and put `* 10^3` on the top of the axis like the figure below?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is sort of a hacky way, but there's nothing wrong with it:

```
plot(x,y/1e3, ylab="y /10^3")
```

Comment: Thanks. It would be better using expressions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302367/concatenate-strings-and-expressions-in-a-plots-title

Answer (score 12):

A similar technique is to use `eaxis` (extended / engineering axis) from the [sfsmisc](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sfsmisc/) package.

It works like this:

```
library(sfsmisc)

x <- c(482563, 922167, 4462665)
y <- c(102, 258, 2314)

plot(x, y, xaxt="n", yaxt="n")

eaxis(1)  # x-axis
eaxis(2)  # y-axis
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

How you get the labels  onto your axis depends upon the used plotting system.(base, ggplot2 or lattice)
You can use functions from `scales` package to format your axis numbers:

```
library(scales)
x <- 10 ^ (1:10)
scientific_format(1)(x)
[1] "1e+01" "1e+02" "1e+03" "1e+04" "1e+05" "1e+06" "1e+07" "1e+08" "1e+09" "1e+10"
```

Here an example using `ggplot2` :

```
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(x  = c(102, 258, 2314),                                                                     
                  y  = c(482563, 922167, 4462665))

qplot(data=dat,x=x,y=y) + 
  scale_y_continuous(label=scientific_format(digits=1))+ 
  theme(axis.text.y =element_text(size=50))
```

[image]

**EDIT** The OP has a specific need. Here some ideas I used here in order to accomplish this :

1. You can customize your plot labels using `axis` function.
2. Use `mtext` to put text in the outer plot region
3. Use expression to profit from the plotmath features...

[image]

```
y <- c(102, 258, 2314)                                                                         
x <- c(482563, 922167, 4462665)
plot(x,y,ylab='',yaxt='n')
mtext(expression(10^3),adj=0,padj=-1,outer=FALSE)
axis(side=2,at=y,labels=round(y/1000,2))
```

Comment: I guess you misunderstood my question; I want 1, 2, 3, 4 with y axis and e+06 to be on the top of the y axis.

Comment: No I understand perfectly your need. My answer was general to invite you to discover R plots features and not to try to reproduce some MATLAB features. Many default R parameters are optimized to easily extract the information from a plot. e.g putting the 10^3, make the plot harder to understand , we are obliged to rescale each time we follow a point...

Comment: I understand that, I'm going to put this into a paper and saving space is my priority here.