# 2 x Concatenate strings and expressions in plot text

Tags: r, plot, expression, title

Similar to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302367/concatenate-strings-and-expressions-in-a-plots-title), but this time I need double.

Here is an example:

```
x1 <- 0
x2 <- 1
plot(c(0,1),c(0,0), type="l", axes=FALSE, main="", ylab="", xlab="")
axis(1, at=c(0, 1), labels=c(bquote(gamma~" = " ~ .(x1)), expression(delta~" = " ~ .(x2))), pos=-.01, xpd=TRUE)
```

The plot labels should should should be:

```
 Gamma = 0     Delta = 1
```

However, take a look when you run for yourself, you get:

```
 Gamma = 0     Delta = .(x2)
```

Note the code below does not work as expected:

```
axis(1, at=c(0, 1), labels=c(bquote(gamma~" = " ~ .(x1)), bquote(delta~" = " ~ .(x2)), pos=-.01, xpd=TRUE)
```

It produces:

```
gamma ~ " = " ~ 0     delta ~ " = " ~ 1
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
axis(1, labels=eval(bquote(expression(gamma == .(x1),delta == .(x2)))),
    at=c(0, 1), pos=-.01, xpd=TRUE)
```

[image]