# R text combine superscript with round and cor functions

Tags: r, text, correlation, superscript

How can I integrate this phrase into the text function:
expression(R^2,"=", round(cor(tkw14_cor$TKW, tkw14_cor$Yield),2))
I also tried 
expression(R^2 == round(cor(tkw14_cor$TKW, tkw14_cor$Yield),2)))
and 
expression(R^2 ~ == ~ round(cor(tkw14_cor$TKW, tkw14_cor$Yield),2)))
and all the 'paste' possibilities..
It does not work like this. 
My goal is to have the text print:
R^2 (as superscript) = rounded correlation coefficient.

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate strings and expressions in a plot's title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302367/concatenate-strings-and-expressions-in-a-plots-title)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `bquote` function.

Random example here:

```
plot(1)
set.seed(1)
value <-  round(cor(rnorm(1000), rnorm(1000)), 2)
text(1,1.2,bquote("R"^"2" ~ " = " ~.(value)))
```