# R: Combine text and mathematical symbols in axis label using barplot

Tags: r, math, expression, bar-chart, axis-labels

I have a barplot and I want to combine text and mathematical symbol in the label of the y axis. The title is too long so I want to separate it into two lines.

The full text would be something like "A lot of text, more text, mathematical expression". So I used mtext to separate into two different lines.

The first line I could do it without any trouble
I use mtext as follows
mtext(side = 2, text = "A lot of text", line = 4)

But in the second line, I cannot concatenate the mathematical expression after more text.
I tried things like this:
mtext(side = 2, text = "more text",expression(Delta*Delta*c[T]), line = 3)

and
mtext(side = 2, text = "more text"~expression(Delta*Delta*c[T]), line = 3)

and of course, didn't work. 
Somebody asked a similar question, but he didn't have two lines and his mathematical expression was at the beginning of the axis title.

[Concatenate strings and expressions in a plot's title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302367/concatenate-strings-and-expressions-in-a-plots-title)

I wonder if there is a way to put the expression between two texts.

Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the answer you linked to indicates, the text and math symbol should both go in `expression(...)`, so

```
par(mar = c(5, 5, 4, 2))
barplot(rpois(5, 10))
mtext(side = 2, text = "A lot of text", line = 4)
mtext(side = 2, text = expression("more text" ~ Delta[T]), line = 3)
```

gives you

[image]

Comment: I solved it by using bquote, 
mtext(side=2, text=bquote("more text" ~ (Delta * Delta * c[T])), line=3)
but thank you so much!! you helped me understand the function expression finally